# symfony: actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, behavior, doctrine-1.2

I've got two little questions:

```
actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
```

What the "~" what mean in the code above?

Then, I've seen that tables with `actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }` have two fields (created_at and updated_at).

Is it possible to bind the updated_at field to a particular field (I update this field, then updated_at get a new value) ?

Comment: `updated_at` is generally used to indicate that *any* field on the record was changed.  Consider creating a separate field for the purpose you've described.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "~" means that you will use default values or default configuration. In your case, the behavior [Timestampable](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine/en/latest/en/manual/behaviors.html#timestampable), will use the default value and configuration. So you don't have to redefine them.

From the doc, here are some configuration:

```
Timestampable:
  created:
    name: created_at
    type: timestamp
    format: Y-m-d H:i:s
  updated:
    disabled: true
```

You will also find this "~" (a lot) in the default `generator.yml`. This way, the generator, even empty, will generate a nice admin:

```
config:
  actions: ~
  fields:  ~
  list:    ~
  filter:  ~
  form:    ~
  edit:    ~
  new:     ~
```

For your second question, the goal of the `Timestampable` is for each modification on a row, the field `updated_at` will be set with the current date. So you don't need to take care of it.

**Edit:**

And if you want to manually update the `updated_at` field:

- first: you will have to disable the timestampable behavior for this field (see the example above
- second: you will have to do the behavior on your own.

The easiest way is to extends the `preSave` function of your model and do the job here. Like:

```
class Article extends BaseArticle
{
  public function preSave($event)
  {
    if(array_key_exists("your_field", $this->getModified())
    {
      $this->setUpdatedAt(time());
    }
  }
```

Comment: ok, perfect thanks. I would like to update the update_at only if only one particular field of my table is modified: is it possible?

Comment: To clarify, ~ is YAML for null.